# Arithmetic in dosbox

Tags: math, x86-16, dosbox

I made an arithmetic program using dosbox. The input is must be 4 and 3 but the result should be 16. Is it true?

```
mov ah, 4
mov al, 3
add ah,ah
add ah,ah
add ah,al
inc ah
```

Answer (score 0):

No, two `add ah,ah` operations cause doubling twice, so result must be `(4 x 2) x 2 + 3 + 1 = 20`

Can you debug assembler code step-by-step looking at register contents?